# Change the function context in JavaScript (for access local variables)

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to run a function in another context where it can access local variables with this context?

I made this proof of concept:

```
var t = (function()
{
    "use strict";
    var ab = 5;

    var f = (function(t)
    {
        return function(c){ c.call(t); }
    })(t);

    return f;

})();

t(function()
{
    return ab;
});
```

This give me this error: ReferenceError: ab is not defined

Is there a way that the anonymous function that I pass to `t` can access the local variable `ab`?

Comment: Imagine debugging that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately (or fortunately) you can't do that. The problem which arises here is that you cannot "pass around" the such called *Activation Object* from a function (context). `Function.prototype.apply` and `.call` can only provide an option to set the context for a function from any regular Javascript Object, but `formal parameter, function declarations and variables` are not stored in any "regular" object. These values are hold in the *Scope chain* underneath and are stored in the such called *Activation Object* (or *Lexical Environment Record*) which you cannot access directly from Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the declaration. It is very useful.
Then, there aren't a form to access a "var" in another context with "call" method?